# configuring swagger with jersey, maven and eclipse

Tags: java, rest, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am trying to configure Swagger for one of REST API projects where Jersey is used. I Followed the [document](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#configure-and-initialize-swagger) for configuring swagger for Jersey-2.

Document states that upon successful configuration one should be able to see swagger.json and swagger.yaml at the context root of the application. But I am getting a 404 error, so confused what is missing here.

pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
     <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>    
        </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.oracle.dis.sysfacade</param-value>
            <!--io.swagger.jaxrs.listing  -->
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/sysfacade/api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Application is deployed in tomcat and I am able to get REST response for

```
http://localhost:8080/sysfacade/api/schemas/1
```

But getting status 404 for the following requests.

```
http://localhost:8080/sysfacade/api/api-docs
http://localhost:8080/sysfacade/api/swagger.json
```

Could not figure out what is missing in the configuration. Am new to Swagger. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your swagger.json file located? Does it end up in the generated war/folder?

Comment: Same issue here, have you managed to get this fixed?